# Python34 - Target Machine Actively Refused Connection

Tags: python, sockets, connection

I've made a simply python script that uses the teamspeak module.
But when trying to connect to any server, including my local one, it returns this.

(I'm semi-new with Python, and help would be appreciated.)

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "endless_poke.py", line 70, in <module>
    with ts3.query.TS3Connection('127.0.0.1', 9987) as ts3conn:
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\ts3\query.py", line 172, in __init__
    self.open(host, port)
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\ts3\query.py", line 249, in open
    self._telnet_conn = telnetlib.Telnet(host, port, timeout)
File "C:\Python34\lib\telnetlib.py", line 221, in __init__
    self.open(host, port, timeout)
File "C:\Python34\lib\telnetlib.py", line 237, in open
    self.sock = socket.create_connection((host, port), timeout)
File "C:\Python34\lib\socket.py", line 509, in create_connection
    raise err
File "C:\Python34\lib\socket.py", line 500, in create_connection
    sock.connect(sa)
ConnectionRefusedError: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.
```

I've seen a few things on the internet, but it's not what I wanted, or it's confusing.

Thanks,
Amos.

Comment: configure your firewall to allow local connections (from/to 127.0.0.1).